# Aborting Ajax call on 'offline' event

Tags: javascript, ajax, internet-explorer

I would like to have my website detect when the user goes offline, and when that happens - abort any on-going Ajax POST calls. At the moment I have the following code in place:

```
$('#form').on('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var post_data = new FormData($("#form")[0]);

    $.ajax({
      xhr: function() {
        var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
        var started_at = new Date();

        xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(evt) {

          if (!navigator.onLine && xhr.readyState < 4) {

            alert("Internet connection was lost. Data transfer has been     aborted.")
            xhr.abort()

          } else {
            // some logic
          }
        }

        return xhr;
    },
    url: '#',
    type: "POST",
    data: post_data,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    dataType: "json",
    timeout: 360000,
    success: function(response) {
        // some logic
    }
  });
})
```

The code above is doing fine with offline event detection as long, as the "progress" event is on, before "load" event fires. However, between "load" event and server response which takes ~1-20sec (due to some server-side data manipulation), I am left with the user waiting for some website reaction, which might never come if the connection is lost.

I have tried to add the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
...
  window.addEventListener('offline', function(e) { 
    console.log('Event checker: offline');
    $.ajax().xhr.abort()
  });
...
})
```

However, that does not work for me one bit - I am pretty sure that the '$.ajax().xhr.abort()' line is not a correct way of trying to kill the Ajax call from outside of the Ajax function.

I have also tried to work with an event listener for 'readyStateChange' event, but states 3 and 4 come only when the server replies, which again leaves me in a situation where connection loss after "progress" event is done will never allow stateChanges 3 and 4 to be perceived.

I have also considered adding timeout property to the Ajax definition, but it is a time designated for completion of readyStates 1-4, so it will be a bit clumsy if I will let the user wait for a few minutes before letting him know his connection timed out and that he should try again...

**UPDATE**

So, I have found a way to implement what I described above, and evaluated it works in Chrome. Pats on the back for me. HOWEVER, Internet Explorer decided to disagree in a spectacular way.

First things first, the code - assigning Ajax definition to a global variable allowed me to reach it via a global event listener:

```
$('#form').on('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var post_data = new FormData($("#form")[0]);

    xhr = $.ajax({
      xhr: function() {
        var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
        var started_at = new Date();

        xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(evt) {

          if (!navigator.onLine && xhr.readyState < 4) {

            alert("Internet connection was lost. Data transfer has been     aborted.")
            xhr.abort()

          } else {
            // some logic
          }
        }

        return xhr;
    },
    url: '#',
    type: "POST",
    data: post_data,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    dataType: "json",
    timeout: 360000,
    success: function(response) {
        // some logic
    }
  });
})


$(document).ready(function() {
...
  window.addEventListener('offline', function(e) { 
    console.log('Event checker: offline');
    xhr.abort()
  });
...
})
```

Chrome understands that code to the letter as I would like it to, BUT Internet Explorer does something hilarious/annoying with the following bit:

```
        xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(evt) {

          if (!navigator.onLine && xhr.readyState < 4) {

            alert("Internet connection was lost. Data transfer has been     aborted.")
            xhr.abort()

          } else {
            // some logic
          }
        }
```

IE actually keeps on calling that bit of code all the time, and if the unlucky user is offline, it will SPAM the screen with endless quantity of alert windows. I am guessing this is some sort of IE's quirky implementation of Ajax's event listeners...

Anyway, does anyone have any ideas on how to fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, 2 days later I finally identified an answer to the problem - it was a race condition, triggered by the following line:

```
alert("Internet connection was lost. Data transfer has been aborted.")
xhr.abort()
```

Re-writing it to the following fixed the issue:

```
xhr.abort()
alert("Internet connection was lost. Data transfer has been aborted.")
```

I have to say this: first time IE was too fast at something. EVER.